# Firefox javascript problem setting variable

Tags: javascript, firefox, variables

i have made a little javascript script that sets a value (named here stock), which i want to make maximum in a drop down list. it will be the maximum value if it is greater that 6.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function selecteazaElement(id,stock)
{
document.addtobasket.idOfSelectedItem.value=id;
var number23=document.addtobasket.number;
number23.options.length=0;
if (stock>=6)
    stock=6;
for (i=1;i<=stock;i++)
{
    //alert ('id: '+id+'; stock: '+stock);
    number23.options[number.options.length]=new Option(i, i);
}
    //window.status="my status";
    } 
  </script>
```

i use this code in this form:

```
     <form id="addtobasket" name="addtobasket" method="POST" action="<?= Route::url('Add         to Basket', array('sale_id' => $sale->id)); ?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="idOfSelectedItem" id="idOfSelectedItem" value="-1">     
    <select name="number" id="number">                 
<option value=0>Choose the number of products</option>                                                         </select>
    <button type="submit" name = "submit" onclick="valbutton(addtobasket");>Adauga in cos</button><br />    
   </fieldset>
   </form>
```

So after the user chooses a product,form a list he can also choose a number(of products)
my problem is:

It works perfectly in chrome and opera, but doesn't display the numbers in the drop down list in Firefox. i wonder why is that?

Thank you!

Comment: @dana Your HTML code is invalid. You're missing the `<fieldset>` tag.

Comment: @dana Also, this is invalid: `onclick="valbutton(addtobasket");`. It should be like so: `onclick="valbutton(addtobasket);"`.

Comment: Please show how and where you are calling the script
Also why <button type="submit" that does not look right and for sure do not have an onclick on a submit button. Instead put the call in the onsubmit of the form

Comment: @dana When and where is `selecteazaElement` called?

Comment: @Šime Vidas ok well if it's not the "id" thing then how can that code have possibly worked properly in Opera or Chrome or whatever (esp. with that event handler syntax error)?  (Not expecting you to know; I'm just scratching my head ... )

Comment: @Pointy I've figured it out. In Chrome and Opera, named elements (elements with a `name` attribute) become global properties, so `number.options.length` from OP's code works. In Firefox, that doesn't work - `document.number` does point to the SELECT element, but just `number` doesn't (unlike Chrome, Opera, ...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is causing the problem in Firefox:

```
number23.options[number.options.length]=new Option(i, i);
```

Change it to:

```
number23.options[number23.options.length]=new Option(i, i);
```

and it will work.

**Your original code:** http://jsfiddle.net/CS6uv/1/ (doesn't work in Firefox)

**Corrected code:** http://jsfiddle.net/CS6uv/2/ (works in Firefox)

Comment: hello, now i have a problem with this code in Safari, it doesn't work properly. any suggestions? thank you!