# javascript not showing properly in safari

Tags: javascript, forms, browser, safari, conflict

I have a javascript code, that sets a maximum quantity that can be select, and a form in which I am using it.

The problem is that, in Safari browser, I actually cannot add a product(the form cannot be submitted)
Any idea why? Thank you ! I put the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function selecteazaElement(id,stock)
{
    document.addtobasket.idOfSelectedItem.value=id;
    var number23=document.addtobasket.number;
    number23.options.length=0;
    if (stock>=6)
        stock=6;
    for (i=1;i<=stock;i++)
    {
        //alert ('id: '+id+'; stock: '+stock);
        number23.options[number23.options.length]=new Option(i, i);
    }
    //window.status="my status";
} 
</script>
```

and i use it here:

```
   <? foreach ($types as $type):?>
     <ul class = "product_types"> 
     <? if ($type->stock_2 > 0):?>
    <li id = 'product_types'><a href="#" onclick='selecteazaElement(<?= $type->id; ?>,<?= $type->stock_2; ?>);'><?= $type->label; ?></a></li>
    <? else: ?>   
    <li id = 'product_unavailable_types'><label><?= $type->label; ?></label></li>
    <? endif; ?>

     </ul>
  <? endforeach; ?>



   <form id="addtobasket" name="addtobasket" method="POST" action="<?= Route::url('Add to Basket', array('sale_id' => $sale->id)); ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="idOfSelectedItem" id="idOfSelectedItem" value="-1">     
   <select name="number" id="number">              
<option value=0>Alege numarul de produse</option>   </select>
   <button type="submit" name = "submit" onclick="addtobasket";>Adauga in cos</button><br />    
</fieldset>
 </form>
```

Comment: Where is the code for valbutton which does not belong to a submit button and also never name a form element "submit"

Comment: no error. i simply cannot add objects to the basket. when i push on the submit button it doesn;t submit.

Comment: @Dana: Please post the relevant code. The code you posted is not called by the form code - my guess is you might try calling submit in the submit event

Comment: Neither is it called in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540658/firefox-javascript-problem-setting-variable

Comment: it is called in the form. it is jquery. see the id of the form

Comment: @Dana please see my answer. We are missing some code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### New Errors:

```
Error: $(".social").jsocial is not a function
Source File: /sales
Line: 184
```

I do not have a number of items to add:
    
    Alege numarul de produse

so if the server needs an amount, it is not getting it, which is why I think you throw that horrible error

If you need addtobasket, you are not calling it correctly

```
<button ;="" onclick="addtobasket" name="submit" type="submit">Adauga in cos</button>
```

---

### OLD ERRORS

```
Error: syntax error
Source File: /sales
Line: 194, Column: 4
Source Code:

    });
```

You need to remove the above from just before the `</script>`

then when I click add to basket, I get the old error I have already posted for you:

```
Error: missing ) after argument list
Source File: /sale/1009/category/52/product/169
Line: 1, Column: 20
Source Code:
valbutton(addtobasket
```

which is the line

`<button type="submit" name = "submit" onclick="valbutton(addtobasket");>Adauga in cos</button><br />`

which needs to be

`<button type="submit" name = "submit" onclick="valbutton(addtobasket)">Adauga in cos</button><br />`

assuming you have a `function valbutton()` anywhere

I also see you have scripts loaded more than once and different versions of the same script - you MUST fix that:

° jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js
° jquery.easing.1.2.js

° coin-slider.js
° coin-slider.min.js

° paginator.js
° paginator.js

° slides.min.jquery.js
° slides.min.jquery.js

Comment: fixed these, still not working in safari (i have not uploaded the code yet. the problem is in that little javascript where i set the maximum products that can be added into basket) though it is weired cause it works on all other browsers

Comment: when you click on a tag (Headache, hang over, etc), that is a product type. and only after you click on that tag, you can choose the number of products to add. still doesn't work :(

Comment: Works for me on Mac, safari 5

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestions - not sure of the end result since I cannot test your code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function selecteazaElement(id,stock) {
  document.addtobasket.idOfSelectedItem.value=id;
  var number23=document.addtobasket.number;
  number23.options.length=0;
  if (stock>6) stock=6;
  for (i=1;i<=stock;i++) {
    number23.options[number23.options.length]=new Option(i, i);
  }
  return false; // cancel the link
} 
function valbutton(theForm) {
 // I still do not know what this does
 if (something wrong) return false; // cancel the form
 .
 .
 return true; // allow form submission
}
</script> 

<li id = 'product_types'><a href="#" onclick='return selecteazaElement(<?= $type->id; ?>,<?= $type->stock_2; ?>);'><?= $type->label; ?></a></li>

<form id="addtobasket" name="addtobasket" onSubmit="return valbutton(this)" 
method="POST" action="<?= Route::url('Add to Basket', array('sale_id' => $sale->id)); ?>">
.
.
<input type="submit" value="Adauga in cos"/><br /> 
</form>
```

Comment: @Dana - please see my changes - ALL my changes. I am off to bed

Comment: thank you, i am going to study them and then feedback to you! have a nice sleep!:)

Comment: nope. i have forgotten valbutton there (i was making some tests) i have edited my code, with the new form, without valbutton (it is useless). still, not working in safari

Comment: @Dana I cannot tell then, if you could post a URL and description of how to see the problem

Comment: ok, go here: http://arpadia-dev.sinergetic.ro/ user: demo@jefbiz.com pass: paris then go here: http://arpadia-dev.sinergetic.ro/sale/1009/category/52/product/169 choose a product and try to submit the form. thank you

Comment: @Dana I now get errors on the server `Kohana_Request_Exception [ 0 ]: Product type not found.`